# How to call 2to3 in Python?

Tags: python

Is there a way I could convert a python2 string to a python3 string by calling `2to3` in python without having to call it via command line?

```
input = 'a=raw_input()'
output = 'a=input()'
```

Answer (score 2):

`2to3` is open source:

https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.10/Lib/lib2to3/

The [`refactor_string`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/lib2to3/refactor.py#L347) function is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mind to add a minimal example, especially on how to initialize `RefactoringTool`?

Comment: For example, `RefactoringTool(fixer_names=['apply'])` gives `ModuleNotFoundError`

Comment: also, given the return is presumably an AST tree, how do you convert that back to the code?